# Hibernate doesn't throw an exception when DB connection fails

Tags: hibernate, exception

I am using hibernate in a java project to do mapping to oracle database.
I was trying to handle exception when give to access to database.
But hibernate seems giving no exception, just stuck there forever.
Could anyone give me some suggestion?
How does hibernate handle exception?
Thank you very much and Merry Christmas:)

Comment: Please try to be a bit more specific: What's your setup? Do you use an application framework like Spring? What database are you running on (which JDBC driver)? How does your datasource configuration look like? What's in the Hibernate log? etc. You cannot expect any help when even the most basic information about your problem is missing.

Comment: hibernate would just wrap a SQL Exception for this case, looks like jdbc does not see a problem with the connection in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If Hibernate isn't throwing an exception, then no exception was thrown from the database driver, implying that your connection hasn't actually failed. If it's just "stuck there forever", as you say, then it's almost certainly just waiting for an executed statement to complete. JDBC drivers and databases in general will just sit and wait/churn forever on a given statement while your app sits idly, waiting for something to come back. You should check what statements are being executed on the database when you see this problem and work on optimizing them.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I am not doing any query. It stuck at the step connecting to database what is not available.

Comment: I don't believe Hibernate obtains a connection until you use a session to do something. Try posting a stack trace.